# Trigger Record Comparison

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I am working on a process that will create a history table when a version is changed for a record in a table.  My trigger is below.  It is working, but it is updating the history table on every update whether the value is different or not.  I would like to only write to the history table if the ProductVersion is different.

Any help would be great.

```
 CREATE TRIGGER UpdateServerControlSqlVersionHistory ON [monitor].[ServerControl]
AFTER UPDATE
 AS

 BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT INTO monitor.ServerSqlVersionHistory
SELECT i.ServerControlID, i.SqlLinkedServerName, i.ProductVersion, d.ProductVersion, GETDATE()
FROM INSERTED i
    FULL OUTER JOIN DELETED d
        ON i.ServerControlID = d.ServerControlID
END
GO
```

Comment: `AND i.ProductVersion <> d.ProductVersion`?

Comment: Tried that now I get two records for each update.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to be sure, as we don't know exactly what update you're doing, but try 
adding that criteria into the join, and switch the join from a `FULL OUTER`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER UpdateServerControlSqlVersionHistory ON [monitor].[ServerControl]
AFTER UPDATE
 AS

 BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT INTO monitor.ServerSqlVersionHistory
SELECT i.ServerControlID, i.SqlLinkedServerName, i.ProductVersion, d.ProductVersion, GETDATE()
FROM INSERTED i
    JOIN DELETED d
        ON i.ServerControlID = d.ServerControlID
        AND i.ProductVersion <> d.ProductVersion
END
GO
```

Comment: This works if there is already a record.  Get no records inserted if nothing exists already.

Comment: @user761786: Its a `CREATE ... AFTER UDPATE` trigger. For that you need an `INSERT` trigger.

Comment: Yes, that is my next step to add logic to check inserts and updates.  My first trigger using the output data.

Comment: But the point is that you won't record inserts (ie "if nothing exists already") until you've got a trigger for that. If this trigger is recording the updates then its done.

Comment: Yes, but I do not want two triggers.  I am going to change my current trigger to after insert and update.  Then add logic on what to do.  Or at least I will try.